# Image resizing with php getting error

Tags: php, image-resizing

I am working on project its about gemstone where I make admin panel where user can upload images  am trying to resize the images it work some how but it give me black output in given dir where I am uploading .
Here is my code .

```
 $target_path = SITE_ROOT .DS. $this->upload_dir .DS. $this->filename;

      // Make sure a file doesn't already exist in the target location
      if(file_exists($target_path)) {
        $this->errors[] = "The file {$this->filename} already exists.";
        return false;
      }
      // i am trying to resize the image
     if( copy ($this->temp_path,$this->filename) or die     ("Could not copy")){
     $imagefile=$this->filename;
   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($this->filename);
   $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($this->new_width,$this->new_height);
   if ($this->type =='jpg') 
   {
       $img = imagecreatefromgif($imagefile);
       imagecopyresampled($image_p, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->new_width,$this->new_height, $width, $height);
       imagegif($image_p,$target_path);
   }
   else{ echo 'something went wrongs';}
   }
        // Attempt to move the file 
        if(move_uploaded_file($this->temp_path, $target_path)) {
        // Success
            // Save a corresponding entry to the database
            if($this->create()) {
                // We are done with temp_path, the file isn't there anymore
                unset($this->temp_path);
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            // File was not moved.
        $this->errors[] = "The file upload failed, possibly due to incorrect permissions on the upload folder.";
        return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all change the imagecopyresampled function to imagecopyresized function.

```
 imagecopyresized($image_p, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width,$new_height, $width, $height);
```

Than change the function from imagecreatefromgif to imagecreatefromjpeg because you are using jpg in if condition.And write the path below i have given like that.

```
  move_uploaded_file($this->temp_path, imagejpeg($image_p,$target_path,100));
```

And sure to unlink if you don't than it will bring you two image files because you are using copy function be sure to unlink.

```
   unlink($this->filename);
```

I have just done it. I hope it will work for you too.

Comment: Welcome and where ever you get stuck .I am here to help

Comment: I will you really helped me out.